# Can't view all Colums using QTableView and my subclass which inherits from QAbstractTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I am learning Qt.

**Most of this code is from a book (The Art of Building Qt Applications)**

My goal: I am trying to create a simple address book model that inherits from QAbstractTableModel. I already implemented rowCount(), columnCount(), data(),headerData(), index(), and parent().

Problem: Only the first Column is showing when I call the QTableView.
I would post an image of the output but I never really answer questions here.. sorry.

```
But the output looks something like this:   
 __________________
|_____Lead________|
|Jim Grayson      |
|Prescilla Winston|
|Melissa Potter   |
|_________________|

It should look something like this:
_________________________________________________________
|_____Lead________|____Title_____|__Phone____|___Notes___|
|Jim Grayson      |     ...      |           |           |
|Prescilla Winston|              |   ....    |           |
|__Melissa Potter_|______________|___________|____...___ |
```

This is the small .csv file I am trying to run

db_small.csv:

```
Lead/Title/Phone/Notes
Jim Grayson/Senior Manager/(555)761-2385/"Spoke Tuesday, he's interested"
Prescilla Winston/Development Director/(555)218-3981/said to call again next week
Melissa Potter/Head of Accounts/(555)791-3471/"Not interested, gave referral"
```

AddresModel.h:

```
#ifndef ADDRESSMODEL_H
#define ADDRESSMODEL_H

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

class AddressModel : public QAbstractTableModel{

private:
    QList<QStringList> addressBook;
    void splitCVSLines(QString &);
public:
    AddressModel(QString& addresses, QObject* parent = 0);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex & index) const;
};
#endif
```

AddressModel.cpp

```
#include "AddressModel.h"
#include <iostream>


AddressModel::AddressModel(QString & addresses, QObject* parent ) 
        : QAbstractTableModel(parent){
    splitCVSLines(addresses);
}


void AddressModel::splitCVSLines(QString & addresses){
    QStringList records = addresses.split('\n');
    QStringList line;
    foreach(QString record, records){
        addressBook.append(record.split('/'));
    }
    foreach(QStringList strlist, addressBook){
        foreach(QString str, strlist){
            std::cout<<"..."<<str.toStdString()<<"...";

        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

int AddressModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return addressBook.count() -2;
}

int AddressModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return (addressBook[0].size());
}


QVariant AddressModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const{
    if(!index.isValid()){
        return QVariant();
    }
    //We are working with the row, always
    QStringList addressRecord = addressBook.at(index.row() +1);
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole){
        return addressRecord.at(index.column());
    }
    if(role == Qt::ToolTipRole){
        QString returnTip, key, value;
        returnTip = "<qt><table>";
        for (int i = 0; i < addressRecord.count(); ++i){
            key = this->headerData(i, Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            value = addressRecord.at(i);
            if(!value.isEmpty()){
                returnTip += QString("<tr><td><b>%1</b>: %2</td></tr>").arg(key, value);
            }
        }
        returnTip += "</table></qt>";
        return returnTip;
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QVariant AddressModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
        int role) const{
    if(orientation == Qt::Horizontal){
        if(role == Qt::DisplayRole){
            return (addressBook[0]).at(section);
        }
    }
    return QAbstractTableModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
}

QModelIndex AddressModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent) const{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return QAbstractTableModel::createIndex(row, column);
}

QModelIndex AddressModel::parent(const QModelIndex & index) const{
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    return QModelIndex();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include "AddressModel.h"

using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        if(argc != 2){
            return std::cerr<<"No!"<<std::endl;
        }
        QApplication a(argc,argv);

        ifstream file;

        file.open(argv[1]);
        string line;
        string alltext;
        while(file){
            getline(file, line);
            alltext += "\n";
            alltext += line;
        }
        file.close();
        QString filetext(QString::fromStdString(alltext));
        AddressModel g(filetext);

        QTableView table;
        table.setModel(&g);
        table.show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
In main.cpp, swop the lines inside your while loop.

```
while(getline(file, line)){
  alltext += line;
  alltext += "\n";
}
```

---

Explanation:

Only the first column is showing up because your columnCount function is currently returning 1.

In the while loop inside the main function, you are adding a '\n' character to the beginning of the alltext string. Inside the splitCVSLines function, you are splitting first by '\n' characters.. so when cycling through the records, the first record has a column count of 1, whilst the rest have a column count of 4.

By swopping the two lines in your while loop, the first record will no longer be an empty line, and therefore your columnCount function will return 4, leading to all data to be displayed.

I also moved the getline to be the condition for the while loop.. this helps prevent the last record to be displayed twice..

Hope this helps.